# Very strange webpack error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

If I use this to run:

```
webpack-dev-server --progress webpack.config.js
```

There are many errors like this:

```
ERROR in ./~/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in E:\study\s-webpack\node_modules\chokidar\lib
 @ ./~/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js 3:9-22
```

However, if I use these to run:

```
webpack-dev-server --progress
webpack-dev-server --progress --color webpack.config.js
```

There is no error.

Here is the code repo: https://github.com/qlqllu/react-webpack-simple/tree/test

It's a very simple react and webpack project.
Please use:

```
npm run good
npm run good2
npm run bad
```

to test.

Comment: As far as I know the config syntax is `--config webpack.config.js` for command line

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your `webpack` config

```
node: {
  fs: "empty"
}
```

Read more about `webpack` configuration [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration)

Then it'll be like

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!